# What's the standard protocol for secure contactless communication

Tags: encryption, smartcard, rfid, nfc

A contactless smartcard has to communicate with a reader in a secure way.

The ICAO standard, for example, defines an encryption key (check BAC, EAC and PACE), so that the communication is not intercepted.

But apart from ICAO (which has its problems, and the infrastructure needed for proper handling of EAC is huge), is there a way for an NFC/RFID reader to communicate with a contactless smartcard without their communication being intercepted.

Roughly speaking - is there a standard protocol that defines something lika a Diffie-Hellman key exchange between card and reader? Or is the standard, typical contactless communication unencrypted?

Comment: I imagine it would be up to the implementator to define the encryption protocol, I would at least assume that a RF communication is not encrypted